# como copiar registros eliminados de una tabla a otra ejecutado directamente en el servidor sin triggers en mysql con C#?

Tags: c#, mysql

Estoy haciendo un programa con un pequeño servidor para registrar ventas, todos los articulos de cada pedido los guardo en una tabla de mysql.

Lo que quisiera es que al eliminar alguna de estas filas pudiera copiarla a una tabla secundaria en la que guardare un registro de los productos "negados", todo esto hacerlo en automatico en el servidor para evitar mandarle informacion por internet por que a veces la conexion no es estable y tarda en reaccionar.

Inicialmente queria hacerlo con un trigger, pero hay otras acciones con las que borro articulos de la tabla y solo quiero que se copien los que yo quiero.

hay alguna forma de ejecutar selectivamente el trigger o se podria realizar de alguna forma con un procedimiento almacenado?

Comment: pero el trigger hay que programarlo tu puedes controlar que es lo que se va a copiar del registro que estas eliminando para crear el historial. Los trigger se ejecutan ante eventos determinados eso es ya ser selectivo

Comment: Hola,
Si la logica que define cual registro borrado va a la tabla secundaria (o sea, no todos los registros borrados deben pasarse a la otra tabla) se encuentra en la aplicacion y no esta modelado en la bd, se me ocurre que puedes hacer 2 cosas:1) migrar la logica al trigger, por lo que cuando se borra el trigger valida si es necesario pasarlo a la otra tabla o no 2) tener una columna de control entonces en vez de borrar, actualizas esa columna con un valor en particular y el trigger verifica que el valor de esa columna y decide si la migra a la otra tabla o no

Comment: Por otro lado, danos mas detalles de la logica del porque no puedes hacerlo con un trigger